# MYSQL - Ordered query with a limit and grouped by two fields

Tags: mysql

I originally posted this, but everything was wrong(unclear, no example, etc) so I took the time to put this together and properly ask this.

This was a question for me in a technical interview and I failed it hard.
I need some insight on how to do it.

Sample table is as such...

Table(Orders)

Fields =
Order ID | Company | Sale | Month

```
Orders
Order ID | Company | Sale | Month
       1 | A       |    7 | Jan
       2 | A       |    3 | Feb
       3 | B       |    2 | Feb
       4 | B       |    8 | Jan
       5 | C       |    4 | Feb 
       6 | C       |    6 | Jan
       7 | B       |    3 | Mar
       8 | C       |    6 | Mar
       9 | A       |    7 | Mar
```

Where the output would be like:

```
 Company | Sale | Month
 B       |    8 | Jan
 A       |    7 | Jan
 C       |    4 | Feb
 A       |    3 | Feb 
 A       |    7 | Mar
 C       |    6 | Mar
```

How do I get the top two companies by Sales per month? (3 months for our purposes)

So I tried this

```
SELECT
Company,
SUM(Sale) AS Total,
Month
FROM Orders
Group by Month, Company
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

Note there are at least 3 companies, and there could be multiple rows for a company in a single month.

If I limit 6, it wouldn't necessarily include all months if that's the case.(If some months are better, I could get 3 entries for one of the months for example, all of Jan is better than Feb)

I got the hint of using a subquery, but even then I was a bit lost.

I tried doing a subquery that returns two companies but do note that the same top two list of companies won't be the same for all the months

So my expected output is 6 rows with varying companies (not always the same 2) and in different order, with different sales, comprised of 3 different top two lists (one for each month) all in one query.

If this is simple, I really bombed my interview but any help would be appreciated.
Hope this is understandable

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Company, SUM(Sale) AS Total, Month,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Month
                              ORDER BY SUM(Sale) DESC) rn
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY Month, Company
)

SELECT Company, Total, Month
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY
    FIELD(Month, 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'),
    Total DESC;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note: It would be much better design to maintain a proper date column for the months.  This way, to sort by month you would not have to resort to an ugly `FIELD` expression to sort the text month abbreviations.